# Why is this function/loop O(log n) and not O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This function is O(log(n)). Why? Isn't it looping up to n?

```
function fxn($n) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i *= 2)
        echo $i;
}
```

I'm pretty new to O(n) analysis by the way. This function sure looks O(n) though since it loops up to n.

Comment: So many good answers that say [almost] exactly the same thing ;-)

Comment: Sorry everyone, I think 1 makes more sense for initializing $i :)

Comment: this might be relevant for anyone wondering about the < vs <= in for the loop condition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557610/big-o-analysis-for-i-n-i-2-vs-i-n-i-2/59557650#59557650

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This loop would be O(n):

```
function fxn($n) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++)
        echo $i;
}
```

Because`$i` takes on the values:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., n
```

But this loop is only O(log(n)):

```
function fxn($n) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i *= 2)
        echo $i;
}
```

Because `$i` takes on the values:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ..., n
```

And a sequence that grows in that manner is called "logarithmic".

Comment: I think your first sample code is `O(1)` because it runs constant number of times.

Comment: @fanjavaid The first function iterates `n` times. As `n` grows, so does the number of iterations of the loop.  If `n` is 1 billion, the loop runs one billion times. This is the standard `O(n)` operation.

Answer (score 9):

It's not looping through all of the elements, in each step it jumps over twice of the elements of the previous step - because of the `$i *= 2` part. That is, assuming that `$i` starts in a value greater than zero, otherwise it's an infinite loop: `$i` will always be `0` as it is written.

Answer (score 8):

Your code loops up to `n` but *not* by ones (or any constant value) which would make it O(n).

*This* is what it does:

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
       |  |     |           |                       |
       +--+-----+-----------+-----------------------+
Steps    1    2        3               4
```

Because it's doubling each time, it's actually O(log N), similar to the way a binary tree search halves the search space on each iteration.

Comment: it's 2 steps from 3-4 and 3 steps from 5-8, etc. right

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** that your function will never end because you're starting at 0, and 0 * 2 = 0. I'll assume your loop starts at 1.

The loop increments by **a multiple of 2** every time, which is why the runtime is `O(lg(n))`.

Let's consider a simple example where n = 128.

here are the values of i for each iteration: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128. Thus, you've gone through 8 values.

```
lg(128) = 7 (lg = log in base 2)
        = 8 - 1
```

Note here that the `- 1` is a constant, so it doesn't affect our runtime calculation.

If the loop incremented by 1 (or any constant, k) the runtime would be O(n). The important thing to consider here is the difference between a **geometric series** and an **arithmetic series**, which gives you different runtimes.