# Big O Analysis for i <= n; i *= 2 vs i < n; i *= 2;

Tags: big-o

Using the example from [Why is this function/loop O(log n) and not O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039098/why-is-this-function-loop-olog-n-and-not-on) :

```
function fxn($n) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i *= 2)
        echo $i;
}
```

Although I can recognize this common pattern in the `for` loop and understand generally that this function is `O(log n)`, I am wondering why this is the case given the condition `i <= n`.

Taken from the above link from an answer from `@paxdiablo`:

```
Inputs 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
       |  |     |           |                       |
       +--+-----+-----------+-----------------------+
Steps   1    2        3               4
```

It makes sense to me that the function is `O(log n)` if the loop had the condition `i < n`.

But if the condition is `i <= n` specifically, `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2)` I don't understand why it is also `O(log n)` because:

- 1 input would require 1 step    (log_2 1 ≠ 1)
- 2 inputs would require 2 steps  (log_2 2 ≠ 2)
- 3 inputs would require 2 steps  (log_2 3 ≠ 2)
- ...
- 16 inputs would require 5 steps (log_2 16 ≠ 5)

Comment: Big-O notation is about performance in the limiting case, which you're very far from.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the condition is `i < n` or `i <= n`, the variable `i` still grows with `i *= 2`.

Comment: @Progman yes `i` grows with `i *= 2`, but the condition of the loop should have an effect on the big O?

Comment: @csguy It does, but not here. For large `n` there is no difference for the time complexity if you have `for (int i=1; i<1_000_000; i *= 2)` or `for (int i=1; i<1_000_001; i *= 2)`. You still need about 20 steps to get to the end, which is `log n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, taking an example of `n=8` for the upper bound, there would be *four* iterations of the loop, not three:

```
i=1, i=2, i=4, i=8
```

This can be expressed as `O(log_2(n) + 1)`.  However, as `n` grows very large, the plus one term would become insignificant, leaving us with just `O(log_2(n))`, as the @paxdiablo answer states.